# Cryptic HRESULT errors

Tags: c++, windows, directx, hresult

The following EndDraw() function returns an HRESULT error code:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The documentation specifies:

> If the method succeeds, it returns S_OK. Otherwise, it returns an HRESULT error code and sets tag1 and tag2 to the tags that were active when the error occurred.
>
> ...and then returns an HRESULT indicating the success of the operations...

I am getting a return value of `-2003238911 (0x88990001)` which doesn't appear on Microsoft's "Common HRESULT values" page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I have also searched for the error code in `WinError.h` but can't find it there either. If it returns this code, there must be a way to find out what it means.

How do I interpret this error code to find out what went wrong?

Comment: http://alax.info/blog/1383 gets you `0x88990001` `D2DERR_WRONG_STATE` and info on thousands (no kidding) of other `HRESULT` codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the Google, on which the top result for that hex code has this:

```
D2DERR_WRONG_STATE
0x88990001
The object was not in the correct state to process the method.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370979(v=vs.85).aspx

I don't know the first thing about graphics programming or Windows programming, but I think this answers your question, combined with the docs stating that the tag values will be given back to you referring to the point where the error occurred.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I know what function call is failing but am not sure why the object is not in the correct state. The error code seems slightly vague!

Comment: For Direct2D and Direct3D debugging, the best thing to do is to enable the "debug device" which should provide additional context and information. See [Direct2D Debug Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee794278.aspx). The only trick here is that the debug layers are OS version specific. You manually download and install Direct2D debugging for Windows 7 RTM, or install the Windows 8.x SDK to get it for Windows 7 SP1 or Windows 8.x. See [Direct3D SDK Debug Layer Tricks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Last but not least..

I got the same error, till i realized that i wasn't calling ID2D1HwndRenderTarget::BeginDraw() first in order to prepare the render target for draw calls.

Answer (score 0):

(I just created an account to vote up the answer by Loul G. but I don't have permission to vote yet...)

I have had this same issue...

When BeginDraw() and EndDraw() are called out of order you can get HRESULT: 0X88990001

Trace back to see the order in which they are called.

Also, to help protect against this you can surround BeginDraw(), EndDraw() calls like:

```
bool beginCalled;
int beginCount;//for debugging
int endCount;//for debugging
//initialize variables somewhere...

void begin(){
   rendTarget>BeginDraw();
   beginCalled = true;
   beginCount++;
}

void end(){
   if(beginCalled){
      rendTarget->EndDraw();
      beginCalled = false;
   }
   endCount++;

} 

//print counts as necessary for debugging
```